# Unable to update each selected product with JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**Background**

In my current project, I have implemented products and a shopping basket using JQuery UI. This is my first attempt to implement JQuery UI but I am sufficient enough with JQuery API. The shop is going to be driven with .Net using c#. I have hit this brick on development which I have searched every corner of the web and turned every page of JQuery API. I just cannot figure out what is wrong with the logic in the code.

**My Problem**

Some of the products have additional options which needs to be selected before it is sent to the shopping basket. Fair enough, so I implemented a dialog form to get the information necessary from the user(JQuery Dialod Modal) and update a table within each product. Everything on the program works until when I update the relevant product with the user input. Every time you update a product the only the first product gets the details. I hope I have explained my problem clearly for you guys... I also included a basic fiddle below simulates the same problem. I

If you click on information icon and hit Add Handle Preferences and fill the information than check the first product again you will see what I mean. Everything gets only printed into the first product. There must be a way to write to each product.

Products are build with HTML unordered list. So an example product would looks like this;

**HTML**

```
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" id="100400">
    <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Option 1</h5>

            <font class="repairDetails" alt="Repair Details" style="">DETAIL
            <font style="color:Red; text-decoration:blink; font-size:1em; bottom:10;">Please view product details for <u>handle preferences</u> before sellecting this option.</font>
            </font><br />
            <label class="price">£00.00</label>

            <a class="ui-icon ui-icon-info dialog_but" title="View Product Detail" href="#" style="">View Product Detail</a>
              <div class="dialog_content" title="" style="">

                    <table  style="border:none !important;">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="border:none !important; width:15px; height:13px !important;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span></td>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                    DETAIL
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="border:none !important; width:15px; height:13px !important;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span></td>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                    DETAIL
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="border:none !important; width:15px; height:13px !important;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span></td>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                    DETAIL
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="border:none !important; width:15px; height:13px !important;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span></td>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">
                     DETAIL
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                    <table id="hDetails" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                    <button id="handle-pre" class="handle-pre">Add Handle Preferance</button>

                    <thead> 
                        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                        Handle Preferences
                            <th>Handle Shape (Pro, Oval, Round)</th><br />
                            <th>Size - SSH/SH/LH/H etc.</th>
                            <th>Specify handle type if sellected <br />Value package re-handle</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="addHere" class="addHere">

                    </tbody>
                    </table>


                    </table>

                </div>
            <a href="" title="Add to chart" class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart chart_but">Add to chart</a>

    <div style="display:none;">

    </div>

</li>
```

**JQUERY**

```
     //Modal window to ask and submit additional user details
        $(function () {
            var hShape = $("#hShape"),
                hSize = $("#hSize"),
                hType = $("#hType"),

        allFields = $([]).add(hShape).add(hSize).add(hType),
        tips = $(".validateTips");

            function updateTips(t) {
                tips
            .text(t)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
                }, 500);
            }


            function checkLength(o, n, min) {

                //check handle shape. Make sure the user only inputs relevent options
                if (n == "Handle Shape") {
                    if (o.val() != "Pro" && o.val() != "Oval" && o.val() != "Round") {
                        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                        updateTips(n + " can only have values of 'Pro', 'Oval' and 'Round'  " + ".");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                //check lenght 
                if (o.val().length < min) {
                    o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                    updateTips(n + " cannot be blank" + ".");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }


            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                show: 'fade',
                hide: 'fade',
                buttons: {
                    "Add Details": function () {
                        var bValid = true;
                        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

                        bValid = bValid && checkLength(hShape, "Handle Shape", 3);
                        bValid = bValid && checkLength(hSize, "Handle Size", 1);
                        bValid = bValid && checkLength(hType, "Handle Type", 3);


                        if (bValid) {
                           $('#addHere').each(function () {
                            $(this).append("<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + hShape.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + hSize.val() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + hType.val() + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>")
                       });
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            });

             $("#handle-pre").live("click", function () {

                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
        });
```

Particularly in the code where I am trying to update the relevant table;

```
if (bValid) {
   $('#addHere').each(function () {
      $(this).append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" + hShape.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + hSize.val() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + hType.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>")
    });
 };
```

Please have a look at the fiddle if my explanation was not sufficient. [Here is the fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/Yygup/2/)

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique.. You are using the same ID for all 3 tables.. and the ID selector will always only get the first element it finds with that ID.  You also need a way to relate the dialog to the relevant table.

Comment: Is what you were looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4R9B6/

Comment: That's awesome and very clever... So, If I am not mistaking you have made the other inputted text non-visible. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as an answer as well.. Thank you so much for the help...

Comment: No, I just inspected the fiddle to see what you had, and noticed that the dialog you wanted was the visible one since the other ones were not visible.  I'll put up an answer with the explanation of why/what changes were needed to help you understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the element by ID which jQuery's id selector will only find the first element that matches the id given.  In your case you can specify the context of which to look for the element

```
// find the main dialog element
var $el = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');

if (bValid) {
     // set the context to the visible div in the background - which is a previous sibling to current dialog
    $('#addHere', $el.prevAll('.ui-dialog:visible')).append("<tr>" + "<td>" + hShape.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + hSize.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + hType.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>")
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4R9B6/

using `$('#addHere', $el.prevAll('.ui-dialog:visible'))` is setting the context in which to find the addHere element.  Which after inspecting the dom, is the previous visible ui-dialog

Also `ID`'s should be unique - so using a class would probably be better though it would be the same solution needed if using classes.